# Liquid template in Azure Logicapp

Tags: liquid, azure-logic-apps

I am new to this Azure liquid templates.
I am having two elements in an json array. Im parsing json to json.

```
**{
  "arrayvalues": [
    {
     "props": [
       {
          "find": "abc",
          "sky": "500"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
     "vu": "500"
    }
]
}**
```

- First i have to check the field called "find". If "find" value is "abc", then i need to get the "sky" field value(that is 500).
- And i need to map this value with 2nd item "vu" value. If it is true then output is like below.

  **{
  "values": [
  {
  "1stlineItem" : "Contains"
  },
  {
  "2ndlineItem" : "True"
  }
  ]
  }**

i have tried the below code. I could assaign the "sky" field value into variable, but after that im unable to map the value with 2nd lineitem "vu" value.

```
**{
  "values": [
  {% for i in content.arrayvalues %}
  {
  {% for properties in i.props %}
  {% if properties.find == "abc" %}
  {% assign sky_name = {{properties.sky}} %}
  {% endif %}
}
]
}**
```

Please help me to resolve this....

Regards,
Vijay

Comment: Could you please ask another question? I will post my answer in your new post.

Comment: I have rolled back this post.

Comment: Sure Frank, I will ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to my `Azure liquid template`:

```
{% assign sky_name = "" %}
{
  "values": [
    {% for i in content.arrayvalues %}
        {% for properties in i.props %}
            {% if properties.find == "abc" %}
            {"1stlineItem" : "Contains"},
            {% assign sky_name = properties.sky %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
            {% assign vu_name = i.vu %}
            {% if vu_name == sky_name %}
            { "2ndlineItem" : "True" }
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
]
}
```

I did some tests, there seems to be no problem:

[image]

Comment: Hi Frank, Its working fine. Thanks for your help.